# Getting issue with custom Shopify webhook (PHP)

Tags: php, shopify

I have created the private app for Shopify in core-PHP. My app was working fine. A few days ago I am getting an issue with my created private APP. when I check the log its show me error on the following line

```
$api_url = shopify-url
$shopify = $api_url . '/admin/webhooks.json'; // webhook json URL
$arguments = array('topic' => 'order/creation',
    'address' => 'https://*********/shopify/print/webhook.php',
    'format' => 'json'
);    // define the arguments 
$webhooks = $api_url . '/admin/webhooks.json', $arguments; // on this line I got the syntax error about ",(comma before the $arguments)".
```

I am confused about this syntax how we can combine string and array into a single variable.
Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: It seems illogical... I guess something has changed your code. Do you have some source-control on it?

Comment: Is the following code is valid? because in my error log file it's showing me a syntax error
     $webhooks = $api_url . '/admin/webhooks.json', $arguments;

Comment: It looks like a leftover from a previous debug instruction like `echo $api_url . '/admin/webhooks.json', $arguments;`.... It does not seem valid to me... but I don't touch PHP much these days...